# Disabling SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, uninstallation

I need to write a script that disables SQL Server Express 2008 from running. This script will be ran on about 500 machines. In my script, I'm setting the start up type for all SQL Windows Services to disabled, and then restart the machine.

In my mind, I have now 100% disabled SQL Server Express from running. I don't care about the orphaned files, someday we might want to turn it back on, so for now, the files can remain.

My Question ...

Is there anything lurking behind that can run, that I'm not considering? Have I totally stopped SQL Server Express from executing, if the services remain disabled?

Comment: you might get more and better answers for something like this on ServerFault - it's more of a sysadmin question

Comment: @codymanix and @richardOD - I need to run the script on 100's of remote controlled, embedded machines in our org.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if no service is running, then sql server is not running since sql server is made up from services.

Why are you asking? Do you want to uninstall and it say that something cannot be deletet because the file is locked?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
net stop "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
```

in the commandline if you do not want to unistall the service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - you're picking up downvotes on this and other answers you've made because the signature is being interpreted as link spam, and by convention is generally unwelcome. Conventions like these keep the signal to noise ratio very high.

Comment: to Paul : Sorry, can you show the convention where it is noted?

Comment: Paul: It's noted here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Bill: okay, but this should be in the place where anyone can see. I can't agree that in Internet everything with SO is a noise and thus - spam. This is an opinion of a single site administration but not the "whole Internet". For example, Technet, MySQL, SQLServerCentral etc. do not make noise beacuse of this. If those are the rules: user has to read them right from the beginning and they must not be somewhere in the "apropos" in some "Forest Codex".

Comment: You are correct - this is the convention here on Stack Overflow, and one that most accept. As Jeff notes in the link above, if you don't like this policy, then maybe participating here isn't for you.

Comment: @Paul Svirin: This has nothing to do with a single site administrators opinion.  If you look at the number of down votes you're receiving the community strongly dislikes the behavior.

Comment: @ RSoldberg: well, I had only post corrections with the guys with 10-15+ k. points. Dut not 300, 400, 500... isn't it an administration?

Answer (score 0):

To disable SQL Express use:

`net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`

To do this in C# you could do:

`string disableSQLExpress = "net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", disableSQLExpress);`

Comment: In c# your command must be execute in Administrator mode.how?

Comment: in your application manifest file you add a line to force the application to run as an administrator